# Is it possible to find the source code where mpmath.siegelz(t) is implemented?

Tags: python

I want to do some work with Riemann zeta functions in Python similar to [this code](https://github.com/azeynel/jupyter-riemann/blob/main/horton-zeros.ipynb) (The code is broken the way it is now)

But I would like to dig a little deeper and understand how `siegelz(t)` is implemented. I’ve looked at mathematical papers where Riemann-Siegel Z-Function is treated, but I want to see how it is implemented in practice. I think that will help me understand it better.

Is it possible to find the source code?

[Documentation page for `siegelz()`](https://mpmath.org/doc/current/functions/zeta.html#siegelz)

Comment: Did you try a google search at all?  https://github.com/mpmath/mpmath/blob/3512b74baa53122269a7e47a35f61e9d96b50725/mpmath/functions/zeta.py#L84

Comment: @No I didn't. My bad. Thanks for the link. Should I close the question?

Comment: I guess it is still a valid question. You can use that link to form a self answer if you like. I would flush it out a bit though, not just a link to the repo. Self answer and once the timer is up you can mark it as the accepted answer.